# OptionalDataException al leer un fichero

Tags: java, archivo

He escrito en un fichero objetos, y a posteriori he escrito en bytes un String.
Después he leído objetos hasta que fuese null el objeto, osea hasta que no encuentre más objetos, y  luego he leído los bytes.
El caso es que se rompe al leer los bytes porque dice que no se ha escrito en el mismo orden en el que estoy leyendo.

Escribir:

```
public void pedirNotas() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("notas.obj");
    ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    double media = 0;
    while(contador<=6) {
        System.out.println("Escribe el nombre de la asignatura");
        String nombre = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Escribe la nota del alumno");
        double nota = sc.nextDouble();
        media=+nota;
        Asignatura asig = new Asignatura(nombre,nota);
        ous.writeObject(asig);
        contador++;
    }
    ous.writeBytes("La nota media es:"+String.valueOf(media/6));
    ous.close();
}
```

Leer:

```
public void leerFichero() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            File file = new File("notas.obj");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            Asignatura asig;
            while((asig = (Asignatura) ois.readObject())!=null) {
                System.out.println(asig);
            }
            System.out.println(ois.readByte());
            ois.close();
        }
        catch(EOFException e) {

        }

    }
```

Excepción:

```
java.io.OptionalDataException
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1759)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:514)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:472)
    at Ejercicio10.Ejercicio10.leerFichero(Ejercicio10.java:39)
    at Ejercicio10.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está bastante bien, el problema es con `ObjectInputStream`, lee los 6 archivos correctamente, pero está identificando en el archivo algunos `bytes` adicionales que aún se pueden leer pero **no son objetos**, por eso está lanzando la excepción.

Una solución que encontré es verificar el método `available()`, devolverá la cantidad de bytes que se leerán, pero devolverá cero siempre que queden objetos, por lo que mientras esté `available() == 0`, siga leyendo, de lo contrario se detiene.

En mi ejemplo a continuación, eliminé el `Scanner` porque era molesto escribir todo.  Pero tienes los mismos 6 objetos con nombre y nota.

```
public void pedirNotas() throws IOException {
    String[] nombres = new String[] {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff"};
    double[] notas = new double[] {4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d};
    
    File file = new File("notas.obj");
    ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    double media = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
        media = +notas[i];
        Asignatura asig = new Asignatura(nombres[i], notas[i]);
        ous.writeObject(asig);
    }
    
    ous.writeBytes("La nota media es:" + String.valueOf(media / 6));
    ous.close();
}

public void leerFichero() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        File file = new File("notas.obj");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        Object tmp;
        while (ois.available() == 0 && (tmp =  ois.readObject()) != null) {
            if (tmp instanceof Asignatura) {
                Asignatura asig = (Asignatura) tmp;
                System.out.println(asig + " - " + asig.nombre);
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(ois.readByte());
        ois.close();
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```